# Why when I go to my odoo website, I didn't go directly to https:// but http:// first?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl, redirect, odoo

I already install the SSL (Let's Encrypt) and use nginx. But why everytime I go to my odoo website with domain and subdomain (portoko.com and andy.portoko.com), it's not immediately use https://portoko.com but http://portoko.com ?

This is my nginx conf :

```
#odoo server
server {
    server_name andy.portoko.com;
     
# Add Content-Security-Policy header
add_header 'Content-Security-Policy' 'upgrade-insecure-requests';

proxy_read_timeout 720s;
proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
proxy_send_timeout 720s;


# Add Headers for odoo proxy mode
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

# log
access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.error.log;

# Redirect requests to odoo backend server
location / {
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_pass http://odoo;
}
location /longpolling {
proxy_pass http://odoochat;
}

# common gzip
gzip_types text/css text/less text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
gzip on;


client_body_in_file_only clean;
client_body_buffer_size 32K;
client_max_body_size 500M;
sendfile on;
send_timeout 600s;
keepalive_timeout 300;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/portoko.com-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/portoko.com-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot




}



server {
    if ($host = andy.portoko.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = andy.portoko.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


listen 80;
server_name andy.portoko.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

I want my website is immediately go to https:// , please help me. Really appreciate every help :D Thank you.

Comment: There is no redirect for your second-level-domain, only for your subdomain. So accessing http://andy.portolo.com should redirect you to https. Is that also not working?

Comment: Hello, actually I made 2 conf, 1 for second-level-domain and 1 for subdomain

Comment: Okay. With that config file the redirect for `http://andy.portoko.com` should still work. Can you have a look at the nginx logs? And that no other server block gets loaded when you access `http://andy.portoko.com`?